# The argument type 'StreamTransformer<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot*, List<Buy>>'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

There are some error in my code. Can you help me to solve it?
Initially, it is FirebaseFirestore and I try to change it to Firebase to match the Firebase version that is required in other modules in my app.

These error occur in the firebase_api.dart

> [1]The argument type 'StreamTransformer<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot*, List<Buy>>'.

> [2]The getter 'cID' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'cID', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'cID'.

> [3]The getter 'cID' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'cID', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'cID'.

firebase_api.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Data/Model/recipeModel.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/ToDo/widget/Utils.dart';
import '../../Data/Model/BuyingListStore.dart';

RecipeModel recipeModel = RecipeModel();
class FirebaseApi {
  static Future<String> createBuy(Buy buy) async {
    final docBuy = Firestore.instance.collection('cart').document();

    buy.cID = docBuy.cID;
                     ^^^[2]
    await docBuy.setData(buy.toJson());
    return docBuy.cID;
                  ^^^[3]
  }

  static Stream<List<Buy>> readBuyingList() => Firestore.instance
      .collection('cart')
      .orderBy(BuyingField.createdTime, descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .transform(Utils.transformer(Buy.fromJson));
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^[1]

  static Future updateBuy(Buy buy) async {
    final docBuy = Firestore.instance.collection('cart').document(buy.cID);
    await docBuy.updateData(buy.toJson());
  }

  static Future deletedBuy(Buy buy) async {
    final docBuy = Firestore.instance.collection('cart').document(buy.cID);
    await docBuy.delete();
  }
}
```

Utils.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Utils {
  static void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) =>
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(text)));

  static DateTime toDateTime(Timestamp value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null!;
    }
    return value.toDate();
  }

  static dynamic fromDateTimeToJson(DateTime date) {
    if (date == null) return null;

    return date.toUtc();
  }

  static StreamTransformer transformer<T>(
          T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson) =>
      StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot, List<T>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (QuerySnapshot data, EventSink<List<T>> sink) {
          final snaps = data.documents.map((doc) => doc.data).toList();
          final objects = snaps.map((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();
          sink.add(objects);
        },
      );
}
```

BuyingListStore.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import '../../ToDo/widget/Utils.dart';

class BuyingField {
  static const createdTime = 'createdTime';
}

class Buy {
  DateTime createdTime;
  String title;
  String cID;
  String description;
  bool isDone;

  Buy({
    required this.createdTime,
    required this.title,
    this.description = '',
    required this.cID,
    this.isDone = false,
  });

  static Buy fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Buy(
        createdTime: Utils.toDateTime(json['createdTime']),
        title: json['title'],
        description: json['description'],
        cID: json['id'],
        isDone: json['isDone'],
      );
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'createdTime': Utils.fromDateTimeToJson(createdTime),
        'title': title,
        'description': description,
        'id': cID,
        'isDone': isDone,
      };
}``
```

How can i change solve this error, so that the buying list can be store using Firestore?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).